# Could you help me to configure the store procedure in the NHibernate config file?

Tags: nhibernate

In my program, i need get a exec a store procedure to decide to get a object from which table, so i need config a stored procedure in my entity nhibernate config file, the config file like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="Entity.ACC.User, Entity" table="ACC_User" lazy="false">
        <id name="Id" column="Id" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0" >
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="Code" column="Code" type="String" length="50" />    
        <property name="Password" column="Password" type="String" length="50" />    
        <property name="FirstName" column="FirstName" type="String" length="50" />  
        <property name="LastName" column="LastName" type="String" length="50" />    
        <property name="Type" column="Type" type="Int16"  />    
        <property name="Email" column="Email" type="String" length="50" />  
        <property name="TelPhone" column="TelPhone" type="String" length="50" />    
        <property name="MobilePhone" column="MobilePhone" type="String" length="50" />  
        <property name="Language" column="Language" type="String" length="50" />    
        <property name="IsActive" column="IsActive" type="Boolean"  />  
        <property name="AccountExpired" column="AccountExpired" type="Boolean"  />  
        <property name="AccountLocked" column="AccountLocked" type="Boolean"  />    
        <property name="PasswordExpired" column="PasswordExpired" type="Boolean"  />    
        <property name="CreateUserId" column="CreateUser" type="Int32" update="false"  />   
        <property name="CreateUserName" column="CreateUserNm" type="String" length="100" update="false" />  
        <property name="CreateDate" column="CreateDate" type="DateTime" update="false"  />  
        <property name="LastModifyUserId" column="LastModifyUser" type="Int32"  />  
        <property name="LastModifyUserName" column="LastModifyUserNm" type="String" length="100" /> 
        <property name="LastModifyDate" column="LastModifyDate" type="DateTime"  />
    <sql-insert>
      exec USP_User_Insert ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
    </sql-insert>
    <sql-update>
      exec USP_User_Update ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
    </sql-update>
    <sql-delete>
      exec USP_User_Delete ?
    </sql-delete>
  </class>
  <sql-query name="User_Select">
    <return class="Entity.ACC,Entity.ACC.User"/>
    exec USP_User_Select ?
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

after i added this query SP in the config file

exec USP_User_Select ?

the program can't run and will throw exception as:

```
unknown class Entity.ACC, Entity.ACC.User
```

what should i do let the SP work.

many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

return class="Entity.ACC,Entity.ACC.User"
line into
return class="Entity.ACC.User, Entity"